# React cross-component states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read [articles](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e#.7grdrb51g) criticizing React for setState being weird when instead the people criticizing it did not understand it properly.
I really like React modularity, and the more I learn it the more I find it intuitive.

Nevertheless, I ran into multiple situations in which I would have liked the states to be cross-component. What I mean is, changing a state in a component could affect another component. It is my understanding that there is no React built in solution to this problem. Of course there are ways around it but there is no fixed protocol.

My question is, why is that? what is the advantage of not providing a simple way to handle such a common scenario? Or if there is and I don't know about it, please enlighten me!

Comment: Have you tried going through callbacks and maintaining the state upper in the hierarchy?

Comment: I mean, I could pass it back through callbacks, but it seems hacky. Also It could be an issue if the components are not nested. At work we created a State class that takes care of this, and it seems really useful in many occasions, thats why I was wondering about a default way of doing this

Comment: What else could you use then unless you introduce a state management system with an API of its own? This is the problem they have been designed to solve.

Comment: That is exactly why I am wondering why React does not have a State management system of its own. I am wondering if there is a technical reason this is not good practice or React just does not support it and I have to introduce one when needed.

Comment: @bebraw,, I am not looking for a way around the problem, I have found one, I am looking for an explanation why this is not supported by default

Comment: You would have to ask the original creators. I suspect it was a conscious choice. The fact that they developed the Flux architecture outside of React gives a clue of that. It simply solves a smaller problem than whole frameworks.

Comment: I hope to find people that work on the project to answer, I know there are several on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 4 out-of-the-box ways to share state between closely related (and unrelated) components: props, callbacks, refs, the ctx variable.

I simply think it's built to be as small as possible with the complete intention that if you need an app state manager for a complex project (where unrelated components need to communicate) that you will include one, and they will not force you into any one approach.

If you did want something with more substantial scaffolding to start a project, which many people do, you could refer to react-boilerplate or similar.

But having React itself limited to the minimal, I have the freedom to choose (or not) the best tool for each project without having to override one-size-fits-all defaults.